# Can I say that the sequence $\left \{\|T_n\|_{\text {op}} \right \}_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $G \subseteq \mathcal L (E)$ be a closed subgroup i.e. a linear Banach Lie  group. Let $$\mathfrak g : = \left \{T \in \mathcal L (E)\ \big |\ e^{tX} \in G, \forall t \in \Bbb R \right \}.$$ Let $\left \{T_n\right \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence in $\mathfrak g$ and $T \in \mathfrak g$ be such that $e^{T_n}$ converges to $e^T$ with respect to the operator norm. Can we say that $\left \{\|T_n\|_{\text {op}} \right \}_{n \geq 1}$ is a bounded sequence of non-negative real numbers? If so, how can I conclude that?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Comment: Thinking aloud: take $T_n:=T+2\pi inI$.

Comment: @Chrystomath take $E = \Bbb C$ and identify $\mathcal L (E)$ with $\Bbb C.$ Then if we take $G = GL(E) = \Bbb C^*$ and consider the sequence $\{2 \pi n i\} \subseteq \mathfrak g$  then $e^{2 \pi n i}$ converges to $1 = e^0.$ It is easy to see that $0 \in \mathfrak g.$ But the original sequence $\{2 \pi n i\}$ blows up.